# Entity Framework providers must declare a static property or field named 'Instance' that returns the singleton instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 in a ASP.NET MVC application. I am using a Code First approach to try and connect to an existing database.

Firstly, I have set up a Model as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PAYCODE { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, I have a Context as follows:

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeContext()
        : base("EmployeeDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Thirdly, I have specified the connection to the DB in the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeDB" connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Finally, I call my context from a Controller class as follows:

```
  var db = new EmployeeContext();
```

However, this throws the following run-time error:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' did not have a static property or field named 'Instance'. Entity Framework providers must declare a static property or field named 'Instance' that returns the singleton instance of the provider.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone can shed some light on this error - I have tried searching on the Web, and have followed Microsoft examples.

Many thanks!

Martin

Added in response to question below:
The following is at the foot of my web.config:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.OracleClient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Do you have the entityFramework section in your Web.config which contains the defaultConnectionFactory and providers elements?

Comment: Hi Andy, I have pasted my <entityFramework> section into the bottom of my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that the error message was caused by trying to use 'System.Data.OracleClient' as a provider for EF6.

It looks to me that this provider cannot be used to connect to Oracle from an EF6 application.

After some searching, I am trying to replace the provider with Devart dotConnect, but the version that my company owns seems to be too out of date to support EF6.

There doesn't seem to be many resources to help with connecting EF6 to Oracle.

Comment: I have opened a new question, as this original problem is kind of answered. Now I just need to get my application talking to Oracle via EF6.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971910/the-entity-framework-provider-type-oracle-manageddataaccess-entityframework-co

Comment: I ended up using the Oracle ODP.NET provider. This works with EF6.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change your connection factory to SqlConnectionFactory. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidobando/archive/2012/08/14/changing-ef-s-default-provider-from-localdb-to-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Hi Steve, I have specified the connection string for my context in the ConnectionStrings section of the config. According to the Microsoft article below I don't need to specify a defaultConnectionFactory because of this. (I did follow your link anyway, and try to change to SqlConnectionFactory, but I still get the same error...)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj556606.aspx