# The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework' could not be loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odp.net

I am trying to connect to Oracle using the Oracle Data Provider.NET (ODP.NET) using Entity Framework v6 in an MVC application.

I have installed ODP.NET from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.entityframework/6.121.1-beta

I have configured my web.config file as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Data Source=MyDatabase; Persist Security Info=False" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />
</connectionStrings>



<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
 </entityFramework>
```

However, when I try to call my EF Context, I get the following error:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application

I have spent a lot of time searching for help with this. Would be very grateful for any help!

Thanks!

Martin

Comment: I have deleted the references to the Nuget package, and copied the DLL's directly into my app's bin folder, and set up references to them there. The app now throws the following error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed." (The DLL looks installed to me! I can see it in references, and it displays in the Object Browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this section to the web.config, along with the steps above, seems to have fixed this:

```
<system.data>

    <DbProviderFactories>

      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver"
           invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
           description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>

</system.data>
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I couldn't connect to Oracle by specifying the TNS name from TNSNAMES,ORA in the connection string. I to paste the below into the connection string:  <add name="MyName" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyDB))); User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />

Answer (score 2):

There can be your framework problem. Please check your framework by right clicking on project--> properties check it is 4.5 version.

And then right click on Refrences--> Manage NuGet Package.. go to the nuget.org and type "**Official Oracle ODP.NET**" in search box. and install Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework.
Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver.
Oracle Data Provider for .Net x84/x64.

Thanking you